# REST - share URI templates in Hypermedia with large data sets?

Tags: rest, hypermedia

I'm building a REST application that intends to be fully hypermedia drive. Consumers of the service will hit an entry point and from then on will follow links. However, I've got a massive list of child resources for a parent - e.g. orders/1 orders/2 ... orders/5000000000

It's very difficult to provide efficient navigation for this, because clients may have to make hundreds of requests. I'm thinking a URI template is the way to go. Is it recommended? Is it RESTful? How do I present URI templates in a standard way that will be understood by others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URI templates are certainly REST - they are simply semi-advanced hypermedia controls. Hypermedia can be more than just links - think of forms in HTML which are hypermedia controls for either GET/POST requests and their payloads.

> How do I present URI templates in a standard way that will be understood by others?

You can use one of the hypermedia enabled media types. For instance [Mason](https://github.com/JornWildt/Mason) or [Siren](https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren) to mention a few.

Comment: thankyou. I actually discovered Hypermedia and Links which I am using.